# PHP logic to Javascript front into html tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am currently trying to convert a lot of backend code to front end (to lighten the load on a small system).

The code at the moment calls a PHP function to return specific information. (e.g. image locations, strings, styling)

I am converting this code to its js equivalent, the content from Mysql was converted to JSON and stored in a read only file and I am accessing that file using this code:

```
<script>
  function jsread(tag) {
    $.getJSON("/strings.json", function(result){   
      document.write(result[tag]['value']);
    });
  }
</script>
```

I want the function to "print" where ever it is invoked. document write writes the value to the page but stops all other loading and write only the value.

Let me be very clear on this: **I DO NOT** want to use anything that needs extra calls or references out side of this function, that will take months of work so no getting elements by their IDs I have already view many questions on this subject and none are what I can work with. I need something that can be applied to every situation. Other wise I will just have to read the JSON using PHP as a middle compromise.

Comment: Let me be very clear on this: **Do not use `document.write()`** as it has its own crazy effects on different browsers, and well, use only `.innerHTML` or `$(element).text()` and update the stuff.

Comment: @PraveenKumar is there a way to use them without a direct reference?

Comment: @SamColeman Try: `$("body").append(result[tag]['value'])`. Simple. No worries.

Comment: @PraveenKumar sadly that did not work to my needs,  <a href="#" ><script>jsread('eur_header')</script></a> <-- hopfully you will see what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @PraveenKumar that code is where I need the text to be displayed within the HTML. I need the Text in a very specific place which may or may not have an ID and there could be multiple of the same tags...I am trying to clean up a front end that I have been left with.

Comment: @qwertyuiop Show your full HTML, so that we can find a better way to target that element. You can also have a placeholder and replace it with the contents. Do you wanna do that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, `document.write()`'s behaviour is crazy across all the browsers, because, it directly modifies the `document` object and messes up with the events attached. So it is always better to avoid this function as each browser defines it differently and has a different effect on the same code, with different browsers.

> *Is there a way to use them without a direct reference?*

**Solution**

The wise thing is, as I said in the comments, it is better to use one of the jQuery functions safely, which create a `textNode` and insert it the right way, without affecting the others:

```
<script>
  function jsread(tag) {
    $.getJSON("/strings.json", function(result){   
      $("body").append(result[tag]['value']);
    });
  }
</script>
```

In case, if you wanna do something like having a placeholder and doing stuff, then you can try giving something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  var data = "Dummy Data, that would probably get returned from the getJSON";
  // Inside the Success function, do this:
  $("span.placeholder-of-the-json").replaceWith(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><span class="placeholder-of-the-json">This gets replaced</span></a>
```

Comment: I used this code you have to me and it appened to the end of the body tag. I am a PHP developer not a front end guy so maybe I am missing a key point

Comment: @qwertyuiop Yes, that's what `$("body").append()` does. `.append()`s to the `"body"`. What else would you expect? So what exactly want to happen in this?

Comment: @qwertyuiop Check the above stuff.

Comment: @qwertyuiop This something just to do with the client side, right? Show the generated HTML alone.

Comment: yes this is what i am trying to acheive I will most likely do this for all text... though I might have some issues with images...

Comment: @qwertyuiop No issues. Let me how it goes and ask your queries here.

Comment: 1 query I have... have if I want to use this in an image src?